# How to access a variable created in JavaScript in ASP

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web

I have a variable that I'm defining in JavaScript:

```
<script>
  var foo = 5;
</script>

<%  
  For i = foo To 10  
    'do something...
  Next  
%>
```

Currently the access to `foo` does not work; how can I access the value? Should I use a form? Please note that I'm using classic ASP not ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1):

ASP is on server side, and Javascript is on cliente side, you can't do this. You can submit variable value by form.